# One Month Rails | Image Upload with Paperclip - missing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am following the One Month Rail course and I have this problem: I used the Paperclip gem to take care of the image uploading. I followed the instructions; however, when I upload my image, it does not display correctly, but instead display a missing image

Screenshot of Chrome Console: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2570626/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-06%20at%209.51.13%20AM.png

My Github folder is: https://github.com/phanatuan/pinteresting

Really appreciate your help,

Tuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `pins/_form.html.erb` partial you mistyped your `file_field` for `:image`

Replace:

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

Everything else is ok.

Comment: Perfect. Mattan runs through this part really quick, so I missed that as well